# In my flutter app, Last two product are not completely showing

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-listview, flutter-gridview

To display the product I have used ListView.builder(). I am show only 20 products for now but last 2 products are not completely displayed. It doesnot show any error in debug Console or on screen.

I have tired using GridView.builder and stagged_grid_view.

Comment: please put the code here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.